# How do I keep from activating facetime while on a call

Tags: iphone

When making a call my cheek hits the screen and turns on facetime etc.

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 2):

Modern touchscreen phones have a proximity sensor, that emits IR light and measures the bounce back from nearby objects (if any). It's meant to detect your phone's proximity to your face. Perhaps you have a malfunctioning proximity sensor that's never detecting your face.

Does your screen go black when you cover the top (from the top of the display and up) with a finger?

Comment: I've having the same problem as the OP, but it only started after upgrading to iOS 9 and I've had the same iPhone for two years... never happened to me under iOS 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

Actually once the phone is answered or ringing just hit the lock button on the top of the phone. It should still continue to operate as a phone but you have locked out the screen.

Comment: Unless you're on speaker phone or have headphones plugged in, pressing the power button will hang up the call.